# Purpose of high pass filter for AC Mains?

Tags: capacitor, ac, filter

I wanted to ask what the purpose of the high pass filter does in the below circuit. Is it necessary?

[image]

Comment: Is it from a LED lamp by any chance, because that is a common technique to ballast them?

Comment: As winny mentioned, it is used in LED circuits. Check out "transformerless power supply"

Comment: I hate to state the bleedin' obvious, but why would they fit it if it wasn't?

Comment: Could I call it a capacitive dropper without discharge resistor but with a current limiting resistor?

Answer (score 4):

> Is it necessary?

If it isn't there you have full mains voltage on the bridge rectifier.

The capacitor has an impedance to AC given by \$ Z = \frac {1}{\omega C} = \frac {1}{2 \pi f C} \$ where *f* is the mains frequency. The result is that it will drop the voltage to the load and, since it is a capacitor, there will be very little power dissipated in it and this eliminates the heating problem associated with a resistor voltage dropper.

Please be aware that this circuit provides no isolation from the mains and that the low voltage side must be considered live.

Comment: Thanks. Since it drops the remaining voltage efficiently, this circuit is a current limiting circuit - not a high pass filter - right? Also, can I get rid of the 27 ohm resistor since it doesn't really affect the overall impedance?

Comment: Yes, it is current limiting. The 27 ohm resistor may be required to limit the current to a safe value in the case when the mains is at a high voltage at the moment of switch on. I advise you to study the theory behind these very carefully before building one.